# Gnuplot how to set a variable to standard-input if not passed

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, gnuplot, stdin

I have a gnuplot script (plot.script) that is invoked like

```
C:> ffmpeg -i '.\my_awesome_audio_file.wav' -filter_complex aformat=channel_layouts=mono -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 4000 -f data - | gnuplot -e "fileout='plot';fileformat='png';wid=500;" .\plot.script
```

Now I'd want to default filein variable to stdin if it is not passed as argument. This because I want to be able to call this script as a 1-liner command with ffmpeg data generation and also as step-by-step procedure

My idea was to use

```
if(!exists('filein')){
filein = '-';
}
```

but this throws  `warning: Skipping data file with no valid points`

if i print the variable datafile I got `-` (I expected something like stdin).

this is the `plot.script` script:

```
if(!exists('filein')){
    filein = '-';
    }

if (!exists("hei")){
    hei = 4444;
    }
if (!exists("wid")){
    wid = 5555;
    }
if(!exists("fileformat")){
     fileformat = 'png';
     }
if(!exists("fileout")){
     fileout = 'risultato';
   }
   
fileout = fileout . '.' . fileformat;
   
if(!exists("dataformat")){
    dataformat = '%int16';
    }
if(fileformat eq 'png'){
  set terminal png transparent size larghezza,altezza;
  
  }else{
  set terminal fileformat size wid,hei;
  }
  set output fileout;
  unset key;
  unset tics;
  unset border;
  set lmargin 0;
  set rmargin 0;
  set tmargin 0;
  set bmargin 0;


print filein;
plot filein binary filetype=bin format=dataformat endian=little array=1:0 with lines linecolor "0x009900";
```

But I also want to call this command-by-command:
generate the data-file:

```
c:> ffmpeg -i '.\my_awesome_audio_file.wav' -filter_complex aformat=channel_layouts=mono -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 4000 -f data audio.dat
```

plot the data:

```
c:> gnuplot -e "filein='audio.dat';fileout='plot';fileformat='png';wid=500;" .\plot.script
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways you might deal with this, but my suggestion is to have gnuplot plot from a pipe opened by the shell command that calls it. It is then up to the shell to fill that pipe either via `cat` from an existing file or by directing a stream to it.  Here is the relevant section from the documentation (see `help pipes`)

```
 On systems with an fdopen() function, data can be read from an arbitrary file
 descriptor attached to either a file or pipe.  To read from file descriptor
 `n` use `'<&n'`.  This allows you to easily pipe in several data files in a
 single call from a POSIX shell:

       $ gnuplot -p -e "plot '<&3', '<&4'" 3<data-3 4<data-4
       $ ./gnuplot 5< <(myprogram -with -options)
       gnuplot> plot '<&5'
```